# The srcset= strings on the website are https links, but when I use selenium's driver.find('img')['srcset'], it gives me base64 strings

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, src, srcset

I'm trying to scrape images from a website. In the website's html code, the srcset sections exist and are of the form

srcset="https://...."

For example,

srcset="https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/80458162/resize-h300-w300%5Ecompr-r85/1068/106844956/Derry+84%2522+Reversible+Sectional.jpg 300w,https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/19496430/resize-h400-w400%5Ecompr-r85/1068/106844956/Derry+84%2522+Reversible+Sectional.jpg 400w,https://secure.img1-fg.wfcdn.com/im/75516274/resize-h500-w500%5Ecompr-r85/1068/106844956/Derry+84%2522+Reversible+Sectional.jpg 500w"

However, when I try to get these srcset link using selenium and beautiful soup, I get the following:

`"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

Moreover, every time the srcset fails to get a valid link, the string that it gets is always

`"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

I tried a bunch of different lines of code, but haven't had success with any of it. Here is the full code I currently have:

```
def get_info_from_product_link(product_link):  #get the price and correctly filtered image link
    info = dict()
        
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Brian/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(200)
    
    try:
        driver.get(product_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        time.sleep(60)
        
        image_carousel = soup.find_all('li', {"class" : "ProductDetailImageCarouselVariantB-carouselItem"})
        print("Number of images in gallery: ", len(image_carousel))
        #deal with captcha
        while len(image_carousel) <= 0:
            print("CAPTCHA ENCOUNTERED. FIX")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            image_carousel = soup.find_all('li', {"class" : "ProductDetailImageCarouselVariantB-carouselItem"})
            time.sleep(30)
    
        valid_image_links = []
        highest_resolution_images = []
        #get correct image links
        #i = 1
        for image_block in image_carousel:
            try:
                #print("image_block:")
                #print(image_block)
                #print("Image: ", i)
                #i += 1
                images = image_block.find('div', {"class" : "ImageComponent ImageComponent--overlay"})
                #image_links = images.find('img').get_attribute('srcset').split(',')
                print(images)
                #driver.implicitly_wait(60)
                #wait = WebDriverWait(images, 30)
                #image_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.tagName, "img"))).get_attribute("srcset").split(',')
                #image_links = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.tagName, 'img'), "https")).get_attribute("srcset").split(',')             
                #image_links = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img [srcset*='https']"), "https")).get_attribute("srcset").split(',')
                #image_links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src*='https']"))).get_attribute("src").split(',')
                
                images.implicitly_wait(30)
                image_links = images.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('srcset').split(',')
                
                #"div[class='ajax_enabled'] [style='display:block']"
                #image_links = images.find('img')['srcset'].split(',')
                
                #print("Image links:")
                #print(image_links)
                #print("Number of links: ", len(image_links))
                for link in image_links:
                    print(link)

                for image_info in image_links:
                    image_link = image_info.split(" ")[0]

                    try:
                        if hasValidBackground(image_link) and hasValidSize(image_link):
                            valid_image_links.append(image_link)     
                        else:
                            print("Invalid image size or background")
                    except:
                        print('ERROR when reading image:  ' + image_link)
                        continue
                
                if len(valid_image_links) > 0:
                    highest_resolution_images.append(valid_image_links[-1])
                    valid_image_links.clear()
                
            except:
                print("Error. Invalid image link.")
                pass
              

        
        #extract one link to a correctly filtered image
        
        if len(highest_resolution_images) <= 0:
            return -1
        
        valid_image_link = highest_resolution_images[0];
        info['img_url'] = valid_image_link
        
        #get price information
 
        standard_price_block = soup.find('div', {"class" : "StandardPriceBlock"})
        base_price_block = standard_price_block.find('div', {"class" : "BasePriceBlock BasePriceBlock--highlight"})
        
        if base_price_block is None:
            base_price_block = standard_price_block.find('div', {"class" : "BasePriceBlock"})
        base_price = base_price_block.find('span').text    
        #price_block = soup.find('span', {"class" : "notranslate"})
        #base_price = standard_price_block.find('span').text
        info['price'] = base_price
        
        print(base_price)

        #print(f"Image link: {image_link}\n")
        #print(f"Link to product: {product_link}\n")

        driver.close()
        #browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])
        return info
    
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Page Load Timeout Occurred. Quitting...")
        driver.close()
```

I was testing using this website:
https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/foundstone-derry-84-reversible-sectional-w001832490.html

My goal is to process each image in the image gallery/carousel and find one that has white background and has valid size of height >= 80 and width >= 80

I'm just starting to learn web scraping, so any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: It would help to have the URL you're trying to scrape. It would also help to have the full code you're using. I'm unsure of what images means (It should be your webdriver but seems like you're using it for BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Hey @AaronS, I just updated the post to include the code and the website. Thanks for your help!